# Show that $\int^t _{0} x_n(s) ds = y_n z_n (t)$ for given $x_n(t)$, $y_n$ and $z_n(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Define $x_n (t) = 2^{j/2} H(2^j t - k)$, with $n = 2^j - k$, $j \geq 0$, $0 \leq k < 2^j $, and

$H(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ for } 0 \leq t< 1/2\\
-1, \text{ for } 1/2 \leq t<1 \\
0, \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$

Show that $\int^t _{0} x_n(s) ds = y_n z_n (t)$, with

$y_n = \frac{1}{2} 2^{-j/2}$ for $n = 2^j + k$, $j \geq 0$, $0 \leq k < 2^j $, and

$z_n(t) = z(2^j t - k)$, with

$z(t) = 
\begin{cases}
2t, \text{ for } 0 \leq t< 1/2\\
-2(t-1), \text{ for } 1/2 \leq t<1 \\
0, \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$

I have

$\int^t _{0} x_n(s) ds = 2^{j/2} \int^t _{0}  H(2^j s - k) ds = 2^{j/2} \cdot 2^{-j}\int^{2^j t - k} _{-k}  H(a) da $

with substitution $a = 2^j s - k$.

The outcome of this integral is $2^{j/2} \cdot 2^{-j} \cdot 2^j t = 2^{j/2} t$, for $0 \leq 2^j t - k < \frac{1}{2}$. This is not what I should get. How to proceed?